# Datatable Angular 4

Tags: angular, datatables

[ANGULAR 4 - ts]
I'm using the metronic theme and its datatable comes from a remote location this way:

```
var DatatableJsonRemoteDemo = function () {
//== Private functions

// basic demo
var demo = function () {

    var datatable = $('.m_datatable').mDatatable({
        // datasource definition
        data: {
            type: 'remote',
            source: 'http://localhost/ci/api/Users',
            pageSize: 10,
            saveState: {
                cookie: true,
                webstorage: true
            }
        },
```

But my API uses a heaader where I have to pass a KEY, how can I do that to fit this request to a key? And where can I by a console.log to see my return? PS: step via post Thanks

Comment: Just checking: is this an AngularJS or Angular question?

Comment: Angular 4 is my problem

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Metronic with **Angular v5.0.5**.
In order to create a Datatable from a remote location you need to,

**import the Service** that gets the key you need

`import { KeyService } from '../path.to.services/key.service';`

Then **call it** in the component constructor

`constructor (private _keyService:KeyService) {}`

In the *ngOnInit()* hook, create your array of options, (I will focus only on the data part)

```
let options = {
      data: {
        type: 'remote',
        source: {
            read: {
              url: 'http://your_API_URL.com',
              method: 'POST',
              headers: { 'Key': this._keyService.getKey()},
            }
        },
        pageSize: 10,
        saveState: {
          cookie: true,
          webstorage: true
        }
      }
```

and create your datatable with

`let yourdatatable = (<any>$('#TheIdDataTable')).mDatatable(options);`

**Notes :**

- If you want to use the GET method you need to have at least the 5.0.4 version of Metronic because before the POST method was hardcoded in the theme. See [this](http://keenthemes.com/forums/topic/metronic-datatable-ajax-method-get-and-append-token-to-header/)
- To use a console.log just put it anywhere you want in the constructor or ngOnInit hook.
- If you just want to see the return of you API request just go in the network section of your navigator console, filter the request by *XHR and fetch* and find the one corresponding to your datatable (something like `users?datatable%5Bquery%5D=`)
- in order to display your results you may need to map them with a function, I invite you to read the [Metronic Documentation](http://keenthemes.com/metronic/documentation.html#sec14) and look for the data.source.read.map part.

Good luck !